# Question about order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $x,y$ are two elements of a finite group $G$ both with order $p$, where $p$ is a prime. And $<x>\neq <y>$. I'm thinking about the order of $xy$.

For example, in $D_p=\{x,y|x^p=y^2=1\}$, $x$ and $xy$ have order $p$ and $xxy$ has order $p$.

So I guess in general, $xy$ has order $p$ (of course in the case that the finite group $G$ is not abelian), but I can't prove or disprove that. May I have some hints?

Rivision: Sorry, I know it's wrong. (1 2) and (1 3) have order 2 in $S_n$ but (1 2)(1 3)=(1 3 2) with order 3.

So it may be good to find out the conditions make the statement become true.

Comment: This would be a very hard question to answer. All you are asking for is: "if $x$ and $y$ are elements of prime order which don't commute, when does the product have the same prime order?".

Comment: Yes. It is exactly my question.

Comment: Note that in general (*i.e.*, without assuming anything about the group), you really can't deduce anything about the order of $xy$ from the orders of $x$ and $y$, not even that it is finite if the orders of $x$ and $y$ are finite.

Comment: I would suspect that $xy$ has order $2p$ but I wouldn't believe it until I proved it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we restrict to groups of prime power order, then order of $xy$ can be large, which is hard to determine, as "knsam" said.

For example, in the dihedral group of order $2^{n+1}$, if we take $x$ and $y$ to be elements of order $2$, then order of $xy$ is among $\{1,2,,...,2^{n}\}$, and each case here is possible.

If you want to consider the case $p>2$, then we may pass from dihedral groups to $p$-groups of maximal class, and almost similar phenomena occurs (that order of $xy$ can be $1,p,p^2,...$. Since discussing $p$-groups of maximal class here may not be too relevant, I completer this short answer here.